# Negate a Search Ansible

Tags: ansible

Looking for a little logic help here. I’m looking to fail out of a playbook. When the IOS version of a device `does not begin with 15.` Here’s the block I have so far, just can’t seem to figure out the not logic. This fails of course when the device is in fact running IOS 15.x.

```
  - name: VALIDATE IOS VERSION
    fail:
      msg: "Device is not Running IOS 15 or Greater Please Upgrade"
    when: ansible_net_version | search("^15\.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just gotta add `not` :)

```
- name: VALIDATE IOS VERSION
  fail:
    msg: "Device is not Running IOS 15 or Greater Please Upgrade"
  when: not ansible_net_version | search("^15\.")
```

Answer (score 5):

This pipe syntax is deprecated. Correct syntax now would be:

```
when: ansible_net_version is search("^15.\")
```

or to negate:

```
when: ansible_net_version is not search("^15.\")
```